# How to find all users that have emails in an array in prisma using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

Hi sorry for the confusing question. Basically, I want to find all the users that have emails that are included in the array.

For example I have an array:

`const arr = ['test@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com']`

and I have my model

```
model User {
  id                Int
  username          String
  name              String
  email             String
}
```

I want to do something like

```
const data = await prisma.user.findMany({
     where : {
          email: in arr
    },
     select : {
         id: true
    }
});
```

I have been trying to find a workaround for this for the longest time.

Comment: Why are you looking for a workaround? Just use [that approach](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference/#in) you've been thinking of

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the correct syntax for it. My above code doesn't work.

Comment: That's why I linked the documentation of the correct syntax in my comment.

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't notice maybe from lack of sleep lol. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax for the `in` operator in Prisma.

```js
const arr = ['test@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com']

const data = await prisma.user.findMany({
     where : {
          email: {in: arr}
    },
     select : {
         id: true
    }
});
```

You can read more in the [Prima Client Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#in) in the docs.